# config file for every module in a symfony web application

Tags: symfony, yaml, config

assuming we have a symfony application with several modules
how we can have a .YAML file for each module
and how we can load this last without loading YAML files from other modules
thank you so much

Comment: [Symfony Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/symfony/) might be a better forum for these sorts of open ended questions.  Be prepared to explain what a 'module' is (as opposed to a Symfony bundle) and why you would want some module's config files to be loaded but not others.  In other words, explain the use case.

Comment: @Cerad our application is composed with multiple module ... each module is like an small application contain SRC ENTITY CONTROLLER folder and now we create a config file for every module and we import this last in service.yaml file  but we really want to load a specific module config file and ignore the others

Comment: I am guessing you need to spend some time learning how the Symfony framework works.  In particular, configuration is read once and then used to generate a set of cached php files.  You can't change the config on a request by request basis so the notion of installing a 'module' but not it's config makes little sense within a Symfony application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot load a given config file on demand. Symfony uses compiled container so it's static.